# Use a marquee in a div only if there is overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, marquee

I want to scroll text (marquee) in a div tag ONLY when the text overflows.

I have the marquee setup, and I am using the [jQuery Marquee plugin](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html). Everything works beautifully with the marquee, but I don't need it to scroll if the text fits on one line.

The page where I am working is here: http://lbrannonent.com/BigCountry247/index.html. The "Title", "Artist", and "Up Next" scrolling fields all need to only scroll if there is overflow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't that how it works? It seems to only scroll if the content overflows for me?

Comment: @Marcel: If you take a look at the link: http://lbrannonent.com/BigCountry247/index.html in the top-right corner the title, artist, and up next information is all bouncing back and forth. I only need it to scroll if the contents do not fit on one line. The scrolling would reveal the remainder of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hrMeS/) that i made for your question. It should give you the idea what to do.

Comment: @Coding-Freak: I'm a little confused. My span id is already defined in another script. How can I get this script to work in conjunction?

Comment: The main objective behind this script was to show the use of `width()` function of JQuery for CSS elements. You can see the if conditions used in the JS code, there you will get the idea of what I tried to do. If not then please post in some code for reference

Comment: @Luke: What Coding-Freak is showing is pretty basic, if you don't see how to implement that in your own code I'm afraid there's no helping you...

Comment: @Luke - if you understood the answer, and it was useful to you, then dont forget to mark the answer as correct by clicking the small tick-mark on the left to this answer. This helps other users to get help in future from this question, and you are rewarded points.

Comment: @Abe Petrillo - I think SO is meant for helping in logic and snippets. Not in full code, isnt it?

Comment: @Abe Petrillo: there are other variables in my code that you are not considering. If you are going to be negative and rude, then don't post anything at all.

Comment: Pardon me for trying to get some help.

Comment: @Luke - buddy we all come to SO to solve problems, sometimes our and sometimes others. So no one can consider himself as rookie or expert. all are the same, all are friends.

Comment: http://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_overflow-style.cfm overflow style is supposed to come and fix this. but not yet.

Comment: if you've got elements with fixed widths involved in your layout, you probably want to be checking against scrollWidth, not width, to see whether you need to use the marquee.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery, consider this:

```
$(".marquee").each(function() {
  if($(this).prop('scrollWidth') > $(this).parent().width())
    $(this).wrap('<marquee></marquee>')
});
```

Give the divs you only want to have scrolling on overflow the class marquee instead of using a marquee tag, and as long as that's before any other code that manipulates the marquee (event handler assignment I assume) it shouldn't matter what else you're doing with it.